# Blazor WASM PWA - PWA feature not working with github pages

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, integrity

I am struggling few days because of integrity check. I am trying to deploy Blazor WASM to github pages but no luck with PWA. I tried everything from here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19796 but still not working.

**Does anyone successfully deployed Blazor WASM PWA (NET7.0) to github pages and have public repo so I can have a look?**

You can find repo of published project here (I implemented Steve Sanderson code so it differs from a template now):
https://github.com/Laftek/BlazorApp1

You can find repo of Blazor WASM PWA (not published) here:
https://github.com/Laftek/BlazorWASMPWAStaticPublish

Thank you!

Comment: Definitely works: https://brianlparker.github.io/BlazorIconGenerator/

Comment: Follow this tutorial: https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/fix-blazor-webassembly-pwa-integrity-checks. You can also check the [yaml](https://github.com/Jimmys20/BlazorComponents/blob/f91c3d92274ecb6f5bc4e97466dc846d2db8d28d/.github/workflows/main.yml) I use to deploy one of my own Blazor WASM projects to GitHub pages.

Comment: Thanks Dimitris :) Now its working! its funny because I followed swimburger to do initial deploy but didnt get to read this. 

@BrianParker Nice webapp!